# How to find a vector normal to a circle?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, analytic-geometry, proof-explanation, circles

Assume $S_1$  be the disk in the $ y = 1$  plane bounded by the circle $ x^2$  +$ z^2$  = $9$ . Prove that the rightward pointing unit normal to $ S_1$ is  the vector $ (0, 1, 0)$.

I know that the gradient is orthogonal to level curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $f(x,y,z)=y-1$, then we have $\nabla f=(0,1,0)$ and $\|\nabla f\|=1$. This unit vector $\frac{\nabla f}{\|\nabla f\|}=\nabla f=(0,1,0)$ is normal to $S_1=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ due to the fact that

> the gradient is orthogonal to level curves

and it is indeed rightward pointing.

The circle only puts a bound on $x$ and $z$, which is not used here.

Comment: Why isn't the circle's $ x$  and $ y$  used here?

Comment: @Lasuiqw because the unit vector $(0,1,0)$ is independent of $x$ and $z$. The vector is exactly the same on the full plane $y=1$.

Comment: The $ y=1$  plane is orthogonal to the circle?

Comment: @Lasuiqw Yes, but that doesn't matter. You only need to use the fact that *the gradient $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to level curves $f^{-1}(\{0\})$*.

Comment: How do you know $ f(x,y,z) =y-1$  is the level curve?

Comment: @Lasuiqw $f(x,y,z) =y-1=0$ is the level curve (which is equivalent to the set of points $y=1$).

Answer (score 1):

Since the curve lies in the xz plane, it seems sort of trival to say that the vector normal to the curve is normal to the plane.

In a more general case you might do something like.

$x = 3\cos t\\
y = 1\\
z = 3\sin t$

$\frac {dr}{dt} = 3(-\sin t,0, \cos t)\\
T = \frac {dr}{dS} = (-\sin t,0, \cos t)\\
N = \frac {dT}{dS} = (-\cos t,0, -\sin t)\\
B = T\times N = (0,1,0)$

Comment: The normal vector and tangent vector are parallel to the circle and the binormal vector is orthogonal to both the tangent and normal vector?